# Pop-up instructing me to start Geth with "repccorsdomain" when running Mist on OSX?

Tags: mist, security, synchronization

Macbook Pro
OS X 10.10.5
Mist/Ethereum-Wallet 0.8.1
Node type: Geth 1.4.10 (Go)

When running Ethereum-Wallet I have been receiving this pop-up message (presumably from within the application) quite regularly:

[image]

> Unable to connect. Please start geth with the following options:
>
> geth --rpc --rpccorsdomain "https://wallet.ethereum.org"
>
> Optional add: --unlock <yourAccount>.

This does not prevented me from syncing with the network; nor have I experienced any problems with transactions or my balance.

Is this a potential security issue I, and other users, should be concerned about?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is saying that Mist cannot connect to **geth**'s [endpoint](https://github.com/ethereum/wiki/wiki/JSON-RPC) (due to the [same origin policy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Same-origin_policy) of most browsers (which are expected to be used when interacting with **geth**)).

The second suggestion is necessary only when making transactions to the block chain (which require private key recovery for signing).

You can sync since **geth**'s functionality is not concerned, only the apps interfacing with it. This is clearly not a security issue as it's how **geth** (and all current implementation of Ethereum clients) was designed and expected to work.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend that, when you launch Geth manually for use within Mist/Ethereum-Wallet, you do not use the `--rpc` flags, but instead rely on the IPC file.

For the web page you open in Mist to work, it needs to initialise web3 gracefully. See https://github.com/ethereum/wiki/wiki/JavaScript-API#adding-web3.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion Xavier. I'm not really familiar with the coding side of things yet, so just making sure I am using best practices as a user (ie, choosing the appropriate node, backing up my files, ensuring my everything is secure) for the moment. Will look into it the future though.

Answer (score 0):

I found that switching between networks "corrects" this problem.

1. `Develop / Network / Testnet`; then
2. `Develop / Network / Main network`